# Windows Server 2008 virtualization without Intel VT

Tags: windows, vmware, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc, sharepoint

I don't have a machine capable of Intel VT ("Virtualization Technology"), but I was assigned to do certain experiments with `Windows Server 2008 R1 / R2` and `SharePoint 2008 / 2010`. I tried installing `Windows Server 2008 R2 x64` using both `Virtual PC 2007 SP1` and `VMware Workstation 7`, and the first tells me it can't work with x64 operating systems, while the latter tells me I would need a `VT` enabled CPU, which I have no access to.

- **Model: Toshiba Satellite L505**
- O/S: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x86
- CPU: Intel Pentium Dual Core T4400 @ 2.20GHz
- RAM: 3GB DDR2
- hard drive: 80 GB free

Is there a workaround for this? How much would I need to downgrade in order to be able to work with my current setup (e.g., `Windows Server 2008 R1 x86` and `SharePoint 2008 x86`, perhaps switching to `Windows 7 Ultimate x86` for my main system)?

**Edit:**
The solution was simple:

- Host: Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x86
- Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 SP1 x86
- Guest: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R1 SP2 x86
- Microsoft SharePoint 2007 SP2 x86

More: [Installing MOSS 2007 on Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008](http://andreasglaser.net/post/2008/08/14/Installing-MOSS-2007-on-Windows-Server-2008-and-SQL-Server-2008-Part-1-Overview.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need VT to virtualise systems of the same architecture - VT is needed to run 64 bit guests on a 32 bit host. You would either need to upgrade your host to x64 or downgrade your guest to x86 as you have